# Express Schema Validation to determine payload structure

Tags: express, express-validator

I am using `express-validator` to determine if the payload being received is in the right structure (schema). Mostly, I want to make sure the object properties exists and that the data is the correct type.

I tried to implement a simple version of this, but it seems to be proceeding past this validation even though my payload doesn't match the defined schema.

```
 // Payload body

{
    "topic1": "data-ingest",
    "data1": {
        "fName": "Bob",
        "lName": "Jones",
    },
    "blah": "no"
}



/**
    * Receive a payload
    */
app.post('/payload', checkSchema({
    topic: {
        in: ['body'],
        exists: {
            errorMessage: 'Missing Topic'
        }
    }
}),
(req, res) => {
    ... Normal Stuff ...
})
```

In this case, I expect my payload to contain `topic` as a key and throw an error message if it's not there.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Joi for schema validations. https://github.com/hapijs/joi

The above code with joi will look like

> Updated answer

```
const Joi = require("@hapi/joi");

const schema = Joi.object().keys({
  topic: Joi.string().required(),
  data: Joi.object()
    .unknown(true)
    .required(),
  blah: Joi.string()
});


/**
    * Receive a payload
    */
app.post('/payload', (req, res) => {
const result = schema.validate(req.body);

if(result.error){
//process the error
}
    ... Normal Stuff ...
})
```

You can find working example at https://runkit.com/ns23/express-schema-validation

Comment: I tried using this but haven't been able to figure out how to create an "unknown" object. `topic` and `data` are always required, however the key/values within `data` are unknown. I just want to ensure that those two primary keys exist and that data is of type object.